# Tkinter: How to handle new lines in a textarea and save them as a single entry?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have a notes saving app on tkinter. When i write a para in my textarea then it is saving as a single entry in saved notes but when i use enter key like if i go to next line or we can say if i make a list, then each line is saving as a separate entry. How to resolve this. here is my save function

```
def save_note():
note = text.get("1.0", "end-1c")
if note:
    with open("notes.txt", "a") as file:
        file.write(note + "\n")
    text.delete("1.0", tk.END)
    text.see(tk.END)
    load_notes()
else:
    messagebox.showwarning("Leere Notiz", "Bitte geben Sie eine Notiz ein.")
```

Comment: What's your Python version?

Comment: my python version is "3.11"

Comment: I'm using Python 3.12, but I cannot run ur script. If I do Python 3.12, it will work for me with no minor changes.

Comment: line 6, in save_note
    note = text.get("1.0", tk.END).strip()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Entry.get() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

Comment: Is `text` an `Entry` widget or a `Text` widget? You used the word "textarea" but tkinter doesn't have a widget by that name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way. It will work.

```
def save_note():
    note = text.get("1.0", tk.END).strip()
    note = note.replace('\n', ' ')
    note = note.replace('\r', '')
    if note:
        with open("notes.txt", "a") as file:
            file.write(note + "\n")
        text.delete("1.0", tk.END)
        text.see(tk.END)
        load_notes()
    else:
        messagebox.showwarning("Leere Notiz", "Bitte geben Sie eine Notiz ein.")
```

Comment: thanks it worked but Can u make 1 more change like if i enter a list in few lines then it should save as a list in saved notes but here it is saving in a single line. Kindly help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76604417/14116211

@Husnain
Here I did some improvement. It can be helpful

Comment: no the issue is still same

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change your text with replace function `file.write(note.replace("\n", "") + "\n")`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Easier way to do this. Using Walrus and f-string format.

Noticed, you don't need parameters for Entry widget.

- Use Walrus, so we don't need duplicate `note`
- Remove parameter for Entry widget.
- Use f-string format `f'{note}' + "\n"`
- Replace 1.0 to 0 for `Entry.delete`.

This is practical way I do this.

Snippet modified same as your script:

```
def save_note() -> str:
    if note := text.get():
    #if note:
        with open("notes.txt", "a") as file:
            file.write(f'{note}' + "\n")
        text.delete(0, tk.END)
        text.see(tk.END)
        load_notes()
    else:
        messagebox.showwarning("Leere Notiz", "Bitte geben Sie eine Notiz ein.")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have improved something here. It can be useful

```
def save_note():
    note = text.get("1.0", tk.END).strip()
    note = note.replace('\r\n', '\n')
    if note:
        lines = note.split('\n')
        if len(lines) > 1:
            note = '\n'.join(['- ' + line for line in lines]) 
        with open("notes.txt", "a") as file:
            file.write(note + "\n")
        text.delete("1.0", tk.END)
        text.see(tk.END)
        load_notes()
    else:
        messagebox.showwarning("Leere Notiz", "Bitte geben Sie eine Notiz ein.")
```